# Индикация загрузки php файла

Tags: ajax, php, html, javascript, html5

Есть два файла:
 - *index.html
 - script.php*

HTML файл должен выглядеть **[так](http://imageshack.com/a/img856/8066/bitz.png)**. То есть необходимо сделать индикацию загрузки php файла (прогресс бар). Как это можно реализовать и на чём?

Comment: загрузки в браузер или вы загружаете файл на сервер?

Comment: Сам скрипт выполняется 5-6 секунд, мне и надо его индикацию выполнения

Comment: Первая же строка в [гугле][1]: http://www.queness.com/post/11434/7-javascript-ajax-file-upload-plugins

[1]: https://www.google.ru/search?q=javascript+uploader

Comment: я в свое время делал на nginx через этот модуль и ежесекундные ajax-запросы: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadProgressModule  
Из плюсов - никакого флеша, никаких лишних обработчиков, никаких заморочек с переносимостью и зависимостью от php (кроме полной комплектации nginx, конечно)  
вроде бы можно еще настроить http upload module так, чтобы потом не приходилось сохранять файлы через php, но этого дзена я так и не постиг.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну если вам нада просто показать что сервак не завис а идет обработка - то я бы поставил тупо GIF с анимацией прогрессбара - естественно он не будет показывать процент отработки скрипта и скоко осталось.

Если же нада заморачиватся  с тем, чтоб показать сколько реально отработал скрипт, скоко еще осталось - то я бы сделал так.
Отправляем Ajax запрос на основной скрипт. До получения ответа вешаем обработчик ,в котором опять же переодически загружает файл к примеру XML в котором 1 цифра (естественно с нормальным оформлением) означающие скоко отработал сценарий в % к примеру. А вот в самом Основном скримте вам нада по мере его отработки делать перезапись файла (XML) с новым значением.